# How to pick best ntree value from a caret grid search?

Tags: r, machine-learning, random-forest, r-caret

I have tuned manually on parameters to find best ntree:

```
bestMtry <- 3
control <- trainControl(method = 'repeatedcv',
                                number = 10,
                                repeats = 3,
                                search = 'grid')


storeMaxtrees <- list()
tuneGrid <- expand.grid(.mtry = bestMtry)
for (ntree in c(1000, 1500, 2000)) {
  set.seed(291)
  rf.maxtrees <- train(survived ~ .,
                       data = trainingSet,
                       method = "rf",
                       metric = "Accuracy",
                       tuneGrid = tuneGrid,
                       trControl = control,
                       importance = TRUE,
                       nodesize = 14,
                       maxnodes = 24,
                       ntree = ntree)
  key <- toString(ntree)
  storeMaxtrees[[key]] <- rf.maxtrees
}
resultsTree <- resamples(storeMaxtrees)
summary(resultsTree)
```

Output:

```
Call:
summary.resamples(object = resultsTree)

Models: 1000, 1500, 2000 
Number of resamples: 30 

Accuracy 
          Min.   1st Qu.    Median      Mean   3rd Qu.      Max. NA's
1000 0.7865169 0.8181818 0.8305031 0.8335064 0.8498787 0.8764045    0
1500 0.7865169 0.8181818 0.8305031 0.8319913 0.8522727 0.8764045    0
2000 0.7865169 0.8181818 0.8305031 0.8327446 0.8522727 0.8764045    0

Kappa 
          Min.   1st Qu.    Median      Mean   3rd Qu.      Max. NA's
1000 0.2700461 0.4243663 0.4786274 0.4753027 0.5252316 0.6281808    0
1500 0.2700461 0.4218811 0.4710053 0.4705338 0.5270828 0.6281808    0
2000 0.2700461 0.4218811 0.4786274 0.4721715 0.5270828 0.6281808    0
```

From the output, I can understand that 2000 is the best value for ntree based on Accuracy and Kappa. I want to store the best value of ntree (2000) dynamically. Is there any way something like `best_ntree <- resultsTree.bestTune` ?

Comment: My caret knowledge is rusty (haven't used it for ages), but isn't it `rf.maxtrees$finalModel$ntree`?

Comment: Could be best solution with a single line of code. But, I am getting wrong value after running this line. `[1] 2000`. Shouldn't it be 1000?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store the results from the summary() call, for example:

```
bestMtry <- 3
control <- trainControl(method = 'repeatedcv',number = 5)
data = MASS::Pima.tr                                

storeMaxtrees <- list()
tuneGrid <- expand.grid(.mtry = bestMtry)
for (ntree in c(1000, 1500, 2000)) {
  set.seed(291)
  rf.maxtrees <- train(type ~ .,
                       data = data,
                       method = "rf",
                       metric = "Accuracy",
                       tuneGrid = tuneGrid,
                       trControl = control,
                       importance = TRUE,
                       nodesize = 14,
                       maxnodes = 24,
                       ntree = ntree)
  key <- toString(ntree)
  storeMaxtrees[[key]] <- rf.maxtrees
}
resultsTree <- resamples(storeMaxtrees)
```

We can take the one that has the maximum mean accuracy:

```
res = summary(resultsTree)
res$models[which.max(res$statistics$Accuracy[,"Mean"])]
[1] "1500"
```

You can convert the 1500 in my example to numeric...

Comment: I am getting Null for `res$models[which.max(res$statistics$Accuracy[,"Mean"])]`

https://i.imgur.com/7EPsp9E.png,
https://i.imgur.com/zvWI9Zq.png

any idea, why?

Comment: Hi @user1896653, so sorry i got confused with trying something else, it should be res = summary(resultsTree). see updated answer

Comment: yes, it's working now! Just one confusion, is there any chance that Accuracy for a parameter is best but Kappa is not? I mean we are considering 'Accuracy' only here. Will be safe completely?

Comment: usually accuracy and kappa are very similar for balanced datasets. When it is imbalanced for example 80:20, you cannot use Accuracy, because you predict all to be the majority and still have an accuracy of 80%. Kappa might be more suitable.

Comment: I am thinking of when accuracy might be better...  usually more in terms what you need.. so it boils down to the balance of the class again, for example if it's like 60:40..but your overall aim is to predict correctly, then accuracy will serve your needs